# Add class to $(this) div if scrollbar exists

Tags: jquery

I've read various posts about checking if a div has a scrollbar and that bit of my code works. What I need to do is add a class to a div if the scrollbar exists, but without having to write code for each div in question. If I specifically name the divs using the class or ID then the code works, but I need a way of getting it to work using 'this'.

Here's my code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.innerHeight();
    }
})(jQuery);

$(function(){

if ($('div').hasScrollBar()){
    var scrollObj = $(this);
    scrollObj.addClass('scrollable');
}

});
```

Comment: Can you tell why it have to work using `$(this)` ? Maybe it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
$("div").each(function() {
   if( $(this).hasScrollBar() ) {
      $(this).addClass('scrollable');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `each` to loop through the `div`s, that will give you the correct `this`.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

I think you just want the `each` method:

```
$("div").each(function() {
    if($(this).hasScrollBar()) {
        $(this).addClass('scrollable');
    }
});
```

### Option 2

But if you want to be clever, you can also do it with `filter`:

```
$('div').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).hasScrollBar(); 
}).addClass('scrollable');
```

Demo on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cg3bv/

### Option 3

If you want to be even cleverer, you can use `hasScrollBar` itself as the filter callback:

```
$('div').filter($.fn.hasScrollBar).addClass('scrollable');
```

That would require changing `hasScrollbar` slightly, though:

```
$.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
    return $(this).get(0).scrollHeight > $(this).innerHeight();
}
```

I think you should do it this way. Making `this` the raw DOM element and `$(this)` the wrapped jQuery object is the usual pattern, as opposed to assuming `this` will always be `$`-wrapped already. Besides, if you wrap it twice (i.e. accidentally call `$` on something that's already a JQ object), there will be some performance overhead but it won't break entirely. Trying to call JQ methods on a raw DOM object will simply fail.

Demo on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qd2ZC/